# Maven & Tomcat - настройка

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

В общем, либо у меня что-то идёт не так, как нужно, либо я дурак, либо и то, и то, но я уже откровенно устал искать по англоязычным stackoverflow и прочим местам, помогите мне с этим. Решения там, конечно, есть, но мне, похоже, не помогают. Ну и я новичок со всеми этими...

Проблема заключается в деплое.

Запускаю сервер, пишет данное:

> Artifact <...>:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

Но лог пустой.

На `mvn tomcat:deploy` пишет это:

> [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:2.2: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not f
>   ind artifact org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:jar:2.2 in releases (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
>
> [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:2.2: Plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to
>   find org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat-maven-plugin:jar:2.2 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of releases has elapsed or u
>   pdates are forced
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project <...>: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]

Код в `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>что-то</groupId>
<artifactId>что-то</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>web_first Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>releases</name>
        <url>git:releases://git@bitbucket.org:мой_битбакет/репозиторий</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>snapshots</name>
        <url>git:snapshots://git@bitbucket.org:мой_битбакет/репозиторий</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>        
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>synergian-repo</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>web_first</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>apache-tomcat</server>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>ar.com.synergian</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-git</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.5</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

Что у нас в `settings.xml`:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>apache-tomcat</id>
    <username>юзернейм</username>
    <password>пароль</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Прокси у меня никаких нет, посему не указано и тут.

В `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"></role>
<user username="юзернейм" password="пароль" roles="manager-gui"></user>
```

Действительно устал копаться в англоязычной литературе, форумах и SO, ситуация не меняется никак, может, уже не соображаю, так что не гоните тряпками за фолс-бегинерство.

Comment: Кажись ты взял пример [отсюда](http://programador.ru/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-maven-tomcat/). В консоли если запустить команду: mvn -version, затем mvn tomcat:deploy что пишет?

Comment: @Владимир

`Java version: 1.8.0_102, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`.

Что будет при томкат-деплое, указано в записи.

Comment: Понятно, идем дальше спрашивать, ты же не можешь написать сразу в ответе. Tomcat установлен, запускается без ошибок? Затем в какой IDE собираешь?

Comment: @Владимир, работаю в IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2, Tomcat установлен и запускался, насколько я помню, без ошибок на других проектах.

Comment: Создай простой maven project, запусти и посмотри на ошибки которые пишет.

Comment: @Владимир, не очень хорошо либо я спотыкаюсь на пустом месте: `[2017-05-06 10:06:28,454] Artifact unnamed: Artifact is being deployed, please wait... [2017-05-06 10:06:28,460] Artifact unnamed: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.`. Лога нет, хотя посылает в лог.

Comment: @Владимир, там и не указано ничего по теме, и то, как у меня был создан проект, видео никак не противоречит. Потому, что создавался ровно так же, не доходя до места с import project. Ошибка томката есть, и я думаю теперь, что это связано с ним самим, его настройками или неким непосредственным его окружением.

Comment: замени плагин версией поновее tomcat6-maven-plugin, tomcat7-maven-plugin или tomcat8-maven-plugin, соответственно деплой будет выглядеть mvn tomcat6:deploy, mvn tomcat7:deploy или mvn tomcat8:deploy

Comment: Да, надо обновить версии, может, хоть как-нибудь поможет. И затем, возможно, переустановлю томкат.

Comment: @brenoritvrezorkre Попробуй [таким образом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruG0SkRildo&feature=youtu.be) создать и посмотреть, что получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обновил плагины, томкат, убрал мусор, может, что-то ещё, уже не помню, пока что работает без мучений.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>что-то</groupId>
<artifactId>что-то</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>tomcat8-maven-plugin</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-b05</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <classifier>with-deps</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>web_first</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-r1655215</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>apache-tomcat</server>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

</project>
```